# Instagram goes to browser

Tags: android, eclipse, instagram

I'm making a button to instagram, when I click on it, it takes me directly from the browser, the thing is, I want it to go to the instagram application and if it wasn't in my mobile, it should go to the browser.

I tried two, both of them takes me directly to the browser

The first code:

```
inslink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

  try {
     Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/natgeo");
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
     startActivity(intent);
     } 

  catch (Exception e) {
         Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/natgeo");
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
         startActivity(intent);
     }
  }
});
```

The second code:

```
inslink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

   if (uri.contains("https://i.instagram.com/" )) {
    String natgeo = "natgeo";
        String uri = "instagram://Page/" + natgeo;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        startActivity(intent);

   } else {
        String natgeo = "natgeo";
        String uri = "https://i.instagram.com/" + natgeo;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        startActivity(i);
          } 
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instagram Application doesn't handle path-prefix natgeo.

Read following xml, it's from Instagram application's AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.UrlHandlerActivity" android:exported="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="instagr.am" android:pathPrefix="/p/" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="instagr.am" android:pathPrefix="/p/" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="instagram.com" android:pathPrefix="/p/" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="instagram.com" android:pathPrefix="/p/" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="instagram.com" android:pathPrefix="/_u/" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="instagram.com" android:pathPrefix="/_u/" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="instagram.com" android:pathPrefix="/_uid/" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="instagram.com" android:pathPrefix="/_uid/" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

So, These are URLs-prefix which Instagram application handles:
http://instagr.am/p/ 
https://instagr.am/p/
http://instagram.com/p/
https://instagram.com/p/
http://instagram.com/_u/
https://instagram.com/_u/
http://instagram.com/_uid/
https://instagram.com/_uid/